# Linux parameters sysctl list of the Linux kernel and its explanation

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

Does anyone know where I can find a parameters list of `sysctl` for the linux kernel and its explanation?

I've searched for it and have found nothing. I looked in the kernel headers too with the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kernel have documentation:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ -- several files with `sysctl` in their names describe specific information.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the full list just by running:

```
$ sysctl -a
```

What the individual parameters means depends on your exact kernel version, but you can likely find an explanation for any of the interesting ones using Google or @myaut's links.

Comment: I believe the question was about where to find those values in kernel sources.

Comment: I thought that this parameters had especfied in kernel documentation, but I never found it.
Thank you very much to all !! :-)